# Magento don't show up edited product on front end

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm creating a module to add products from the front-end.When the product is created, it visible in the front-end but once is edited in the back-end don't show up in the front-end. I check WebSite, Stock Options, Visibility, Qty, Categories and everything is fine but don't show up.

Here are the code to see if you find any problem

```
    public function addAction(){
    if($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()){
        $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

        $product->setSku("base");
        $product->setName($postData['service_name']);
        $product->setDescription($postData['descripcion']);
        $product->setShortDescription($postData['descripcion']);

        $product->setOwnerName($postData['owner_name']);
        $product->setEmail($postData['email']);
        $product->setMovil($postData['movil']);
        $product->setTelephone($postData['telephone']);
        $product->setPais($postData['pais']);
        $product->setProvincia($postData['provincia']);
        $product->setCuidad($postData['ciudad']);
        $product->setReparto($postData['reparto']);
        $product->setAddress($postData['address']);
        $product->setServiType($postData['servi_type']);
        $product->setServicios($postData['servicio']);
        $product->setCapacidad($postData['telephone']);

        $product->setAttributeSetId(9); // put your attribute set id here.
        $product->setTypeId('grouped');
        $product->setCategoryIds(array(3)); // put your category ids here
        $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));// put your website ids here
        $product->setPrice(1000);
        $product->setWeight(200);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $product->setStatus(2);
        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock'             => 1,
            'manage_stock'            => 0,
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1
        ));


        try {
            $product->save();

            $group_product_id = $product->getId();
            $simpleProductId = array();
            foreach($postData['habt'] as $habtData){
                $textHabType =strtolower(Mage::helper('octus_services')->getAttribTextValue($habtData['tipo_habitacion'], 'tipo_habitacion'));
                $productGrouped = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                // Dinámicos
                $productGrouped->setSku($textHabType.'_'.$group_product_id);
                $productGrouped->setName($textHabType.'_'.$group_product_id);
                $productGrouped->setTipoHabitacion($habtData['tipo_habitacion']);
                $productGrouped->setBano($habtData['bano']);
                $productGrouped->setPrice($habtData['price']);
                $productGrouped->setDescription($textHabType.'_'.$group_product_id);
                $productGrouped->setShortDescription($textHabType.'_'.$group_product_id);
                $productGrouped->setStockData(array(
                                                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                                                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                                                     'qty' => $habtData['qty']
                                                ));
                //Estáticos
                $productGrouped->setAttributeSetId(10);
                $productGrouped->setTypeId('virtual');
                $productGrouped->setStatus(1);
                $productGrouped->setTaxClassId(0);
                $productGrouped->setPriceType(1);
                $productGrouped->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));
                $productGrouped->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
                $productGrouped->save();
                $simpleProductId[] = $productGrouped->getId();
            }
            $products_links = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');
            // Map each associate product with the grouped product.
            foreach($simpleProductId as $id){
                $products_links->assign ("grouped",$group_product_id,$id);
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Los datos de su alojamiento han sido agregados satisfactoriamente'));
        }catch (Exception $ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curious that the product is visible in the front-end until edited in the admin. Looking at this line...

```
$product->setStatus(2);
```

...it shouldn't show up at all. In the Status attribute, 2 means "Disabled". My guess is that it's visible immediately after saving because your module holds it in memory, but any click away would mean it's back to being unavailable.

```
$product->setStatus(1);
```

Is what you want for "Enabled".

Comment: I saved the product disabled for the group to review if the data are correct and then enable the back-end but after edited is not displayed in the front-end. But if I save the product Enabled with the script then its appears until is edited in the back-end